# How to replace default icon on "Add Media" button?

Tags: post-editor

I want to use a different icon for Add Media button in the standard post editing form. What's the best way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS is the way to go here.

Add a new CSS for admin using the `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook in your child theme functions.php (if you don't have one, [you're doing something wrong](http://docs.presscustomizr.com/article/24-why-and-how-to-create-a-child-theme-with-wordpress))

```php
function my_admin_enqueue_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style('my-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/my-admin.css', array(), '1.0.0');
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_enqueue_style');
```

In your my-admin.css file

```css
/* change the content to another Dashicon */
#wp-content-editor-tools .wp-media-buttons .add_media span.wp-media-buttons-icon::before {
    content: "\f104";
}

/* or set a background-image instead (set content to "" in the rule before) */
#wp-content-editor-tools .wp-media-buttons .add_media span.wp-media-buttons-icon {
    background-image: url(../../wp-content/uploads/2017/10/my-image.png);
    background-position: center;
}
```

[Available Dashicon icons here](https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons)