# How to edit the default icon of Add Media button?

Tags: css, buttons, icon

I am trying to replace the default Add Media icon in my Wordpress site. I searched for the same on the web and got this:

[How to replace default icon on "Add Media" button?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/284217/how-to-replace-default-icon-on-add-media-button)

This seems to work for the OP, and ofcourse should've worked for others too. But, I am getting confused as the answer contains words like Child Theme and all. I could understand the first part of the answer, but I lost the track when the answer talked about this:

```
wp_enqueue_style('my-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/my-admin.css'
```

From where did this part of the url came: `'/css/my-admin.css`. I searched in my database at the backend but couldn't find this particular file anywhere. I know this might be a silly thing to ask, but this is it. Can someone help in this regard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this function `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` return  URI to current theme's stylesheet directory and `/css/my-admin.css` is path to their file which you can create in your theme directory
example :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="my-css" href="https://yourdomain.com/wp-content/themes/yourtheme/css/my-admin.css">
```

this is the output of the code in your source

Comment: I created the my-admin.css file in my backend and entered the css code there. Changed the content to another dashicon too. Didn't work. What did I miss?

Comment: can you see my-admin.css when you see page source ? if you can you should make check your css code

Comment: Thanks, it worked. However, a new issue popped up: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/392077/why-could-i-not-change-the-icon-of-the-default-add-media-button-that-i-added-int

Answer (score 1):

`/css/my-admin.css` is located in the current theme directory as specified from the return value of `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` prepended to this path.